# Add alphabet at specific value in bar graph

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

Here is my code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


#Declaring data
year = []
relative_recurrence = []

#Open data file
f = open('relative recurrence plot.txt','r')
for row in f:
    row = row.split(' ')
    year.append(int(row[0]))
    relative_recurrence.append(float(row[1]))
    
#Plot the graph    
plt.bar(year, relative_recurrence,color = 'grey', label = 'HILDCAAS', edgecolor='black')
plt.xticks(np.arange(min(year), max(year) + 1, 5))

# Label for x-axis
plt.xlabel("YEAR")

# Label for y-axis
plt.ylabel("Relative Occurence")

plt.savefig('recurrence plot.png')
plt.show()
```

After running i got a plot like this:
[image]

I want to make two changes here.
First is: In the x axis the range is 1975 to 2018 and i want to show marking of every year on the x axis but not the year.
Second is :
For some values of x; y is zero, so for zero value i want to add a label 'G' near to x axis.

Please tell the useful code to add to this program.
The data is:
1975 0.916
1976 0
1977 0
1978 1
1979 0.916
1980 0
1981 0
1982 0.75
1983 0.9
1984 1.125
1985 1.5
1986 0.416
1987 1
1988 0
1989 0
1990 1
1991 0
1992 0.4
1993 0.416
1994 0.7
1995 0.5
1996 0.571
1997 0.285
1998 1
1999 0.5
2000 0.545
2001 1
2002 0.333
2003 1.5
2004 0.58
2005 0.454
2006 0.375
2007 0.444
2008 0
2009 0
2010 0
2011 2
2012 1
2013 1
2014 1
2015 2
2016 2
2017 1.42

Comment: Thankssssss a lottttt!!!! I was getting negative views on that. So I deleted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify the plot ticks but keep every labels for every 5 years, you can use `ax.set_xticks(..., minor=True)`. Next, you need to figure out where the zero values are and use `plt.text()` to set the label at this specific location. The following code does this:

```py
plt.bar(year, relative_recurrence,color = 'grey', label = 'HILDCAAS', edgecolor='black')
plt.xticks(np.arange(min(year), max(year) + 1, 5))

ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(min(year), max(year) + 1), minor=True)

# Label for x-axis
plt.xlabel("YEAR")

# Label for y-axis
plt.ylabel("Relative Occurence")


# Find locations where relative_recurrence is 0
xlocs = np.where(np.array(relative_recurrence)==0)[0]
ylocs = np.zeros_like(xlocs) + 0.1

# Plot them in `data` coordinates. I.e. where x_values need to be in years.
xoffset = min(year) - 0.5
for idx in range(len(xlocs)):
    plt.text(xoffset + xlocs[idx], ylocs[idx], 'G')
```

Here's how it looks for me:

[image]

Comment: Hope the data i added may help you

Comment: Thanks. Please see the edits. I originally had plt.xticks() incorrect and I added the plotting of `G`.

Comment: Thankyou. The code worked. However the first query is still unresolved(maybe i wasnt clear). I want to make ticks visible but years to be visible with step size of 5.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood that first query. I edited my answer to accomplish this. I think that should suffice